# need to calculate A^(-x) in finite fields for inverse dft

Tags: finite-fields, fourier-transform, integer-rings

Trying to implement to the dft in finite fields (GF(m = 337) with 8th_unit_root = 85 since my data is of size 8) - in the inverted dft defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_over_a_ring   i need to calculate a^(-j*k).
I don't know how exactly to do that. Do I run modinverse( powmod(a, j*k), m ) or am I wrong ?
There were parts of me who understood it as: powmod ( modinverse( a, m), j*k).

powmod is the exponentiation in modular space.
modinverse is a function to calculate the inverse of a number in modular space.
dft is the discrete fourier transform

thx for any help

Comment: Shouldn't $\text{powmod}$ also accept $m$ as an argument (or $m$ is a global constant)? Your formulae are both correct: they calculate $(a^{jk})^{-1}$ and $(a^{-1})^{jk}$, which are equal to $a^{-jk}$.